# Chrome returns cached version of a file, even when no-cache HTTP-headers are set

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers

I have a SPA application (with Angular Frontend) hosted on a web server and I have the following behavior:

When I deploy a new version and go to `https://my-page.at` (just an example), I somehow get the old version of my `index.html`! In the dev-tools network-tab I can see that the file is returned from Chromes "disk-cache". If I reload the page the correct version is displayed (fetched from the webserver).

That would be ok if we did not disable the cache, but to my best knowledge we did. First I tried with `<meta http-equiv`, e.g. my `index.html` contains the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

This didn't work as expected, so now we use HTTP-Headers from the webserver (we can verify that they are correctly present in the response through the network tab).

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
expires: 0
last-modified: Mon, 13 Mar 2023 08:21:01 GMT
pragma: no-cache
```

Yet the `index.html` is STILL cached! Even weirder: Once you hit F5 and get the new version of the file I would expect to have that one in the Cache. But if I close all tabs and open `https://my-page.at` again, I get the old version **again**!

This behavior is 100% reproducible on my machine (the problem was also reported by customers though, so it's not just my pc). Can't get my head around it, especially the last part.

Why is the cached version returned? How to you prevent that?